# Mock Authentication with name

Tags: java, spring, authentication, junit, mockito

I am testing my Spring MVC app. **The Requirement** is to mock `SecurityContext`, but I need `Authentication` with some name, not null. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my CODE:

```
Authentication auth = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
SecurityContext secCont = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
Mockito.when(secCont.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(auth);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(secCont);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mocked Spring's `Authentication` object here:

```
Authentication auth = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
```

And you have told Spring's `SecurityContextHolder` to store this `Authentication` object here:

```
Mockito.when(secCont.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(auth);
```

So, if you want the mocked `Authentication` object to return "some name" then just set some mock expectations on **it**. For example:

```
Mockito.when(auth.getName()).thenReturn("aName");
```

Comment: You have helped me more in one comment to undestand Mockito than a lot of websites where they don´t mention this stuff (Maybe they do but I wasn´t getting it). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much easier with the Spring annotation `org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser`

```
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "viewUser", authorities = { "view" })
    public void mytest(){}
```